# ExtJS: Send file to a socket server

Tags: extjs, websocket, extjs4.1

I'm using ExtJS 4.1.1 for my client app. I need to upload files to a socket server. I know I can use the WebSocket extension described [here](https://github.com/wilk/ExtJS-WebSocket/blob/master/README.md) to send messages to the socket server. But I'm not sure whether this can work with files.

I'll appreciate advice from anyone who have been faced with such a task before. It doesn't have to be done using the ExtJS WebSocket extension, but it has to be done using ExtJS on the client side. I'm using Netty for my socket server, but I think this is immaterial here.

**UPDATE:**

Following @Ee-P's recommendation, I've tried using [this extension](https://github.com/vincentdieltiens/WebSocketFileTransfer). However, that extension throws the exception `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined`. I can receive the file details on the server side, but I'm not sure how to access the file itself on the server side. I'm not sure whether the actual file is sent or whether it's just the details of the files. @Ee-P mentioned a wrapper class; all I've done is include the JS file and Mootools classes. And then, in my code, I have:

```
if(!WebSocketFileTransfer.supported()) {
            console.log('WebSocket File Transfer is not fully supported by your browser.');
            return;
        }
        var transfer = new WebSocketFileTransfer({
        url: 'ws://localhost:8087/ws',
        file: file,
        blockSize: 1024,
        type: WebSocketFileTransfer.binarySupported() ? 'binary' : 'base64',

        type: 'binary',
        progress: function(event) {
            console.log('File upload in progress');
        },

        success: function(event) {
            console.log('File successfully uploaded.');
        }

        });

        transfer.start();
```

Any idea about what I may be doing wrong or alternatives will be appreciated very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload files with Websocket in an HTML5 browser, you just need to create custom classes that will handle this for you. Its very easy to do so in ExtJS. Just use your custom class in your controller's and you are all set to go. For example, you can use this: https://github.com/vincentdieltiens/WebSocketFileTransfer class and include it in your ExtJS app, then create a wrapper for it and use that on your controllers.

Comment: No problem, I would personally create a singleton class in /app/util and use that to wrap functionality to the WebsocketFileTransfer class. If you need code examples please let me know, I'll fix some up for you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ee-P. I've been away. I'm currently testing it. I'll let you know by end of day. Also, thanks for the offer to assist. I'll first try it out.

Comment: Hello @Ee-P. I've been trying to make this work. When I send a file to the server, I get `TextWebSocketFrame(text: STOR: {"filename":"archived.png","size":1381,"type":"binary","parameters":[]})` on the socket server side. When I send a response back to the client as you've specified (github), I get `Cannot read property 'size' of undefined`.